# Custom URL Scheme for iOS App when not backgrounding

Tags: iphone, ios, url-scheme, deep-linking

I have set up a custom deep-linking iOS URL scheme for my app, and I listen for it in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
```

I parse the URL and send a notification using `NSNotificationCenter`, with the URL as the object, to the appropriate class to handle the URL.

This all works great when the app is "backgrounded" but when the app is fully closed out of multitasking, it seems like the notification never gets sent (or received).  Am I missing something about the process of notifications when the app isn't in backgrounding?  Is there another way to pass along the information from the URL?  Or is there at least a way to tell if the app is coming out of backgrounding or if it is a fresh launch?

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend looking at `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:`. The notifications should be delivered in the launch options dictionary. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Make sure you return `YES` from `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. If either return `NO`, then the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method won't be called on app startup.

Comment: @rmaddy both are returning YES, 'application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:' is getting called, but notification not being passed

Comment: @MikeD checking into that now thanks.

Comment: @MikeD solved using the URL from launch options dictionary.  Thanks, if you want to submit answer I can mark solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the `launchOptions` dictionary that is passed into `applicationDidFinishLuanching:withOptions:`.

For full details on what is included in the options dictionary: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html